# Tipp 10 typing tutor app not launching at all

Tags: software-installation, deb

I downloaded the `.deb` file from this link: [Tipp 10 Download](https://www.tipp10.com/en/download/)

I tried to launch it from Kubuntu drawer and it doesn't open.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not you, it's Tipp10.

#### This answer assumes you have a 64-bit system

If you have a 32-bit system, Tipp10 should run out-of-the-box. If not, please comment and I will try to add instructions.

I used the tarball instead because I didn't like the script installed by the deb. There's no compiling to do, so there's not much benefit to the deb - it has the same dependency issues and APT wouldn't resolve them for me.

If you use the tarball, I would suggest creating a directory in your home (`mkdir tipp10`) and then unpacking it there.

In any case there seems to be only a 32-bit version, which means that if your system is 64-bit (whose isn't these days?) you need to install a whole bunch of 32-bit libraries to run it.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt install libstdc++6:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 \
libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 \
libxcursor1:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 \
libxi6:i386 libsm6:i386
```

This list may not be exhaustive, because I've already installed various things on my 17.04 installation. I will show you how to troubleshoot in a moment...

If you have the tar, `cd` to the place you've put it and unpack

```
tar xzf tipp10*.tar.gz
cd tipp10*0
```

Now try to run the executable.

```
./tipp10
```

If you installed the `.deb` (using the command `sudo dpkg -i tipp10*.deb` in the directory where you downloaded it) you can instead use the command

```
tipp10
```

or more directly

```
/usr/share/tipp10/tipp10
```

In any case, if, when you try to run it, it throws an error like

```
./tipp10: error while loading shared libraries: libfoo.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

then you *should* be able to figure out which library you need to install using

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfoo.so.6
```

replacing `libfoo.so.6` with the name of the missing file from the error. This will return something like

```
libfoo:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfoo.so.6
```

So you would satisfy the dependency by running

```
sudo apt install libfoo:i386
```

Another tip for figuring out the libraries needed by an executable is to use `ldd` with the absolute path, so in the directory `ldd ./tipp10` should show you all the requirements (but you then still have to figure out the name of the package that provides the library...)

Once it does actually run, if you used the tar method you can make a symlink to it in a path location. Let's say you unpacked the tar in the directory `~/tipp10`. You could do

```
sudo ln -s $HOME/tipp10/tipp10_linux_v2-1-0/tipp10 /usr/local/bin/tipp10
```

And then you can run it from anywhere with `tipp10`.